# Read memory failed. How to debug?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging, memory

I'm getting an exception breakpoint which make crash my application in `UIApplicationMain`. The error message is :

`name:<read memory from 0x1b failed (0 of 8 bytes read)> reason:<read memory from 0x23 failed (0 of 8 bytes read)>`

How can I debug this kind of error ?

When I deactivate the exception breakpoint, the app works normally.

Thank you

Comment: "When I deactivate the exception breakpoint, the app works normally" So do that, and move on.